# "Chances of (doing) something" vs. "chances at (doing) something"?

Tags: prepositions, difference, american-english

Could you tell me if *chances of (doing) something* and *chances at (doing) something* mean the same? For example:

> Your chances **of/at** getting a place at the college are high.

I would have thought that the use of the preposition *at* was incorrect there, but Rachel used it instead of *of* in the 14th episode of the 6th season of **Friends**. Here it is:

> Rachel: All right, all right, well you just blew your chances **at** dating Bob!

Is it standard in America to use *at* with *chances*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more often singular ***chance*** rather than ***chances***, but by far the most common preposition is ***of** winning* - with what I assume is a "continuous participle" verb form (but maybe it's a "gerund", I've never found that distinction particularly clear or useful myself).

The next most common form is ***to** win*, which I assume is a preposition use, followed by an "unmarked infinitive" verb form. The preposition ***at*** comes in a distant third in [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chance%20of%20winning%2Cchance%20to%20win%2Cchances%20of%20winning%2Cchances%20to%20win%2Cchance%20at%20winning%2Cchances%20at%20winning&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchance%20of%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20to%20win%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20of%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20to%20win%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20at%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20at%20winning%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchance%20of%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20to%20win%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20of%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20to%20win%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20at%20winning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20at%20winning%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

If you follow my link to that chart, you can toggle between AmE and BrE corpuses for more detail, but I don't think there's any significant difference between them. Feasibly Americans are slightly less likely than Brits to use the plural ***chances***, but learners should probably just stick with the singular anyway, since it's far more common everywhere.

The main point to note is that the preposition is essentially a stylistic choice, primarily affected by the (again, *stylistic*) choice of verb form. That choice doesn't reflect any difference in *meaning*.